# Какая нормальная температура MacBook Pro 15" 2018 при работе с Xcode?

Tags: mac, apple, macbook

Мой мак греется в пассиве (серфе браузера, просмотр видосов) от 45-55 градусов, когда начинается работа с Xcode - температура возрастает от 70-85 градусов. Нормальная ли эта температура мак? Менял термопасту, очищал охлаждение в сервисе. Или может это проблема связанная с процессором?